# wso2esb - outSequence ::unsupported form of compression

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

Created a REST API using WSO-2ESB that fetches XML data on calling the GET operation of another REST Service.

Problem ::
On Adding any tag like

```
<xslt key="gov:resources/removeNS.xslt"/>
```

OR

```
<log level="full" separator=","/>
```

in the **OutSequence** before **SEND**.. i get the following error on calling the service on browser.
[image]

**REST API Code:**

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InvokeASservice" context="/invokeWS" hostname="noiwmehra01906">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="sequence" value="** Request Recieved**"/>
         </log>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/get?id=',get-property('uri.var.str1'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://noiwmehra01906:9765/services/PersonInfoService/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=","/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Can someone explain this behaviour.

Thanks,
Wajid

Comment: rather posting browser issues, you can post ESB logs..Means what error you got from ESB end, what is your log outputs

Comment: The esb log files wso2carbon.log or wso2-esb-service.log do not list any errors. Another Intresting and weird behaviour using the same code:: To get the response formatted in JSON format I have to make follwing entry                                     <outSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=","/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
 If I remove log mediator messageType=application/json has no effect.

Comment: So, you are saying if you keep log mediator you  receive json message, if you remove that you are getting xml message, even if you set the messagetype? In which version of ESB you are facing this issue?

Comment: ##CASE 1##   If I keep Log mediator i get JSON response , after setting messageType=application/json, and if Log mediator is removed there is an XML response ###CASE 2##If i keep Log mediator and set the  messageType=application/xml we get "Parsing Error" on browser but curl works fine, and on removing log mediator xml response is shown on browser too##### ESBvwso2esb-4.6.0 calling wso2as-5.0.1.. Thanks for your constant support...Could replicate it on multiple machines...